# Using RegionPlot and NDSolve to plot areas of species coexistence across 2 parameter space

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, stability

I have four ODEs corresponding to four species:

```
dRdt = g*R (1 - R/k) - c1*M*R - c2*P*R;
dMdt = e1*c1*M*R - c3*Z*M*(1 - s) - M*d1;
dPdt = e2*c2*P*R - c5*Z*P*s - u1*P*(M + P) + u2*R*Z - P*d2;
dZdt = e3*c3*Z*M*(1 - s) + e5*c5*Z*P*s + u1*P*(M + P) - u2*R*Z - Z*d3;
```

I check that everything works by first simulating the dynamics over time:

```
sim = {R -> R[t], M -> M[t], P -> P[t], Z -> Z[t]};

dR = {R'[t] == First@{dRdt /. sim}, R[0] == 1};
dM = {M'[t] == First@{dMdt /. sim}, M[0] == 1};
dP = {P'[t] == First@{dPdt /. sim}, P[0] == 1};
dZ = {Z'[t] == First@{dZdt /. sim}, Z[0] == 1};
```

Assigning my parameters and solving with NDSolve:

```
pars = {g -> 5, k -> 25, c1 -> 1, c2 -> 0.5, c3 -> 0.5, 
   c5 -> 0.5, e1 -> 0.5, e2 -> 0.5, e3 -> 0.5, e5 -> 0.5, d1 -> 0.5, 
   d2 -> 0.5, d3 -> 0.5, u1 -> 0.5, u2 -> 0.5, s -> 0.7};
sol = NDSolve[{{dR, dM, dP, dZ} /. pars}, {R, M, P, Z}, {t, 0, 
    1000}];
```

And finally plotting the simulations across my two variables of interest:

```
Manipulate[
 sol = NDSolve[{{dR, dM, dP, dZ} /. {g -> 5, k -> var1, c1 -> 0.5, 
      c2 -> 0.5, c3 -> 0.5, c5 -> 0.5, e1 -> 0.5, e2 -> 0.5, 
      e3 -> 0.5, e5 -> 0.5, d1 -> 0.5, d2 -> 0.5, d3 -> 0.5, 
      u1 -> 0.5, u2 -> 0.5, s -> var2}}, {R, M, P, Z}, {t, 0, 
    10000}];
 
 Plot[Evaluate[{R[t], M[t], P[t], Z[t]} /.
    First[sol]], {t, 10, 
   10000}, PlotStyle -> cols, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1000}, {0, 10}}],
 
 {{var1, 50}, 0, 100, 1},
 {{var2, 0.7}, 0, 1, 0.01}
 ]
```

This is great because I can use the toggle to visualize when certain species go extinct vs. when they all coexist. Now, I want to show exactly that using RegionPlot. Where I'm stuck is that I'm not sure how to ask RegionPlot to evaluate the areas of all species having equilibrium greater than zero as being True. I've tried the following but I know this is wrong:

```
Table[
 sol = NDSolve[{{dR, dM, dP, dZ} /. {g -> 5, k -> var1, c1 -> 0.5, 
      c2 -> 0.5, c3 -> 0.5, c5 -> 0.5, e1 -> 0.5, e2 -> 0.5, 
      e3 -> 0.5, e5 -> 0.5, d1 -> 0.5, d2 -> 0.5, d3 -> 0.5, 
      u1 -> 0.5, u2 -> 0.5, s -> var2}}, {R, M, P, Z}, {t, 0, 
    10000}];
 
 RegionPlot[
  Evaluate[{R[t], M[t], P[t], Z[t]} /.
     sol] > 0, {0, 100, 1}, {0,
    1, 0.01}],
 
 {{var1, 50}, 0, 100, 1},
 {{var2, 0.7}, 0, 1, 0.01}
 ]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use `NDSolve` to simulate from `t=0` to `t=10000`, and the value at time `t=10000` is used as a proxy for the equilibrium value. For the plot I use `ListContourPlot`:

```
(* OPs code *)
dRdt=g*R (1-R/k)-c1*M*R-c2*P*R;
dMdt=e1*c1*M*R-c3*Z*M*(1-s)-M*d1;
dPdt=e2*c2*P*R-c5*Z*P*s-u1*P*(M+P)+u2*R*Z-P*d2;
dZdt=e3*c3*Z*M*(1-s)+e5*c5*Z*P*s+u1*P*(M+P)-u2*R*Z-Z*d3;
sim={R->R[t],M->M[t],P->P[t],Z->Z[t]};
dR={R'[t]==First@{dRdt/. sim},R[0]==1};
dM={M'[t]==First@{dMdt/. sim},M[0]==1};
dP={P'[t]==First@{dPdt/. sim},P[0]==1};
dZ={Z'[t]==First@{dZdt/. sim},Z[0]==1};

(* adaptation of OPs code *)
aux={g->5,c1->0.5,c2->0.5,c3->0.5,c5->0.5,e1->0.5,e2->0.5,
     e3->0.5,e5->0.5,d1->0.5,d2->0.5,d3->0.5,u1->0.5,u2->0.5};
equilibrium[var1_,var2_,tend_:10000]:=NDSolveValue[{{dR,dM,dP,dZ}/.aux/. {k->var1,s->var2}},             
                                         {R[t],M[t],P[t],Z[t]},{t,0,tend}]/.{t->tend};
                                         
(* simulate, this takes a moment *)
var1s=Range[1,100,0.5];
var2s=Range[0.01,1,0.005];
sim=Outer[{#1,#2,equilibrium[#1,#2]}&,var1s,var2s];

(*plot*)
plotdata[i_]:=Flatten[Map[{#[[1]],#[[2]],#[[3,i]]}&,sim,{2}],1];
plotdata["all"]:=Flatten[Map[{#[[1]],#[[2]],Times@@Chop[Abs[#[[3]]]]^(1/4)}&,sim,{2}],1];
plot[data_,species_,color_]:=ListContourPlot[data,Contours->{0.0001},PlotLabel->"Species "<>species,ContourShading->{None,Opacity[0.2,color]},InterpolationOrder->3,FrameLabel->{"var1","var2"}];
GraphicsGrid[{{plot[plotdata[1],"R",Blue],plot[plotdata[2],"M",Green]},
             {plot[plotdata[3],"P",Yellow],plot[plotdata[4],"Z",Magenta]}}]
plot[plotdata["all"],"ALL",Cyan]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Very neat, thank you! Is there any way to overlay these plots onto one another so that there is one single plot with a shaded region where all species have positive equilibrium?

Comment: @Clara I added another plot. I understand that the contours do not look great, one could work on it. Btw, I hacked this together pretty quickly, and have not checked carefully if the result is plausible, that will be much easier for you to judge. Good luck.

Comment: That is perfect, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Is there a way to do this with Solve instead of NDSolveValue? Solve allows me to identify unstable equilibrium as well with the code: FullSimplify[
 Solve[{(dR /. par) == 0 && R >= 0, (dM /. par) == 0 && 
    M >= 0, (dP /. par) == 0 && P >= 0, (dZ /. par) == 0 && 
    Z >= 0}, {R, M, P, Z}, Reals]] . I'm just unsure how to incorporate the variable manipulations...